# How to group IDs in one column and put into new column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that look like this:

| HR | O2Sat | Temp | DBP | Resp | P_ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 96 | 99.2 | 36.50 | 60.0 | 10.0 | 1 |
| 95 | 100.0 | 39.50 | 68.5 | 12.0 | 1 |
| 110 | 85.8 | 37.95 | 58.5 | 19.2 | 2 |
| 100 | 95.5 | 35.45 | 45.9 | 11.5 | 2 |
| 89 | 98.0 | 38.10 | 65.4 | 10.5 | 3 |
| 98 | 100.0 | 36.50 | 49.5 | 15.8 | 3 |
| 102 | 100.0 | 37.45 | 60.0 | 16.0 | 4 |
| 115 | 95.0 | 38.05 | 55.8 | 14.5 | 4 |

I want to have the 1st two rows (P_ID = 1) under single ID (ID = 1), and so on. So that when I do analysis on basis of patient ID, it will consider all rows having that ID as a group, instead of dealing them as separate rows. Like this:
[image: pic]

How I can do that? Please help.

---

**Update**:

This will be my desired output of my dataframe. This is the time-series data from PhysioNet Sepsis Challenge 2019. I considered every row as a separate patient. But this is not good approach. I want to do my analysis patient wise no matter how many entries (rows) that patient has. Not considering individual row as a separate patient, but the individual row as a data of that patient having unique ID.

[image: wd]

Comment: You can use `pandas.DataFrame.groupby('ID)`. Check [this](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html)

Comment: @Anwarvic Thanks for editing. I dunno why this is not making a table. I faced such bug a fews days ago.

Comment: There is no concept of merged cells in pandas dataframes, could you provide the expected output as a DataFrame or dictionary?

Comment: As much I know, Try this you create a copy of that `P_ID` column and create column `ID` and make it as index `df.set_index('ID', inplace=True)`.
Note : But the position might change of ID as first column

Comment: @mozway The attached image is what I am looking for.

Comment: so you expect to create an image?

Comment: I edited the question. Hope you understand what I want.

Comment: Well, what you want is impossible, eventually `set_index('P_ID')` and if you're using a nice interpreter or a notebook, it will show only the first label, but the concept or merged cells **does not exist**

Comment: I think I am not able to ask properly what I want.

Comment: @Huzaifa - Can you include an example how you would use your desired dataframe differently? I can't imaging a single function that would be different.

Comment: @Huzaifa I am sorry, but I really don't get what you expect…

Comment: Updated the question again. Hope it helps

Comment: @Huzaifa I provided an answer, hope it helps, but be aware that this is OK only for display purposes as you lose information on the IDs here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output you want to get is called `Multi-index` dataframe. As you mentioned the data is from `PhysioNet Sepsis Challenge 2019`, there is a column with `ICULOS` that is an important information for each patient. You can convert your dataframe to a multi-index dataframe including this column also. Like the following:

Suppose you included the `ICULOS` column:

| HR | O2Sat | Temp | DBP | Resp | P_ID | ICULOS |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 96 | 99.2 | 36.50 | 60.0 | 10.0 | 1 | 1 |
| 95 | 100.0 | 39.50 | 68.5 | 12.0 | 1 | 2 |
| 110 | 85.8 | 37.95 | 58.5 | 19.2 | 2 | 1 |
| 100 | 95.5 | 35.45 | 45.9 | 11.5 | 2 | 2 |
| 89 | 98.0 | 38.10 | 65.4 | 10.5 | 3 | 1 |
| 98 | 100.0 | 36.50 | 49.5 | 15.8 | 3 | 2 |
| 102 | 100.0 | 37.45 | 60.0 | 16.0 | 4 | 1 |
| 115 | 95.0 | 38.05 | 55.8 | 14.5 | 4 | 2 |

Simply do this:

```
df1 = df.set_index(["P_ID", "ICULOS"])
df1.head()
# Output:
                   HR   O2Sat   Temp    DBP     Resp
P_ID    ICULOS                  
1          1       96   99.2    36.50   60.0    10.0
           2       95   100.0   39.50   68.5    12.0
2          1       110  85.8    37.95   58.5    19.2
           2       100  95.5    35.45   45.9    11.5
3          1       89   98.0    38.10   65.4    10.5
```

This way you can do your analysis.

Answer (score 1):

Let's imagine the following DataFrame:

```
  col1  col2
0    A     1
1    A     2
2    A     3
3    B     4
4    B     5
5    C     6
6    C     7
7    D     8
```

You can `mask` the `duplicated` keys:

```
df['col1'] = df.mask(df['col1'].duplicated(), '')
```

output:

```
  col1  col2
0    A     1
1          2
2          3
3    B     4
4          5
5    C     6
6          7
7    D     8
```

**NB. be aware that the content of the dataframe changes, now you cannot use the value A in row 2 for instance**

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
df.loc[df['P_ID'].eq(df['P_ID'].shift()), 'P_ID'] = ''
df = df.set_index('P_ID').reset_index()
```

Output:

```
>>> df
  P_ID   HR  O2Sat   Temp   DBP  Resp
0    1   96   99.2  36.50  60.0  10.0
1        95  100.0  39.50  68.5  12.0
2    2  110   85.8  37.95  58.5  19.2
3       100   95.5  35.45  45.9  11.5
4    3   89   98.0  38.10  65.4  10.5
5        98  100.0  36.50  49.5  15.8
6    4  102  100.0  37.45  60.0  16.0
7       115   95.0  38.05  55.8  14.5
```

Comment: I follow the discussion since the beginning

Comment: ok, then I'm glad I was not the only one not to get the question ;)

Comment: Thanks guys @Corralien and mozway